# What is the websocket URL in Ethereum on Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, events, websocket

I've lunched an **Ethereum** server based on **Geth**. Now, I need to be notified about all incoming transactions on my generated accounts.
In my previous Bitcoin Core server, I had an option in its config file like this:

```
walletnotify=php -f /path/notify.php %s
```

Through this code, Bitcoin server sends all events to the specified file, and then, I process other things.
But I don't know what is the exact mechanism to do that in Geth and Ethereum. The [official documents](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/server), only said use `--wsaddr, --wsport, --wsapi` flags. But, where do I have to listen to notifications?

Answer (score 0):

**Websockets**

I'd recommend [this](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) page for an overview of the different flags you can use with Geth on launch. It mentions there that the default address for the websocket (if turned on with `--ws`) is `localhost:8546`.

**Logging all transactions**

I don't think this will output all new txs out-of-the-box, though I am a bit out of my water here. You could use a JavaScript script to accomplish this without websockets or ipc (loading a script with the `--js` flag followed by the path to the script), or you could use subscriptions. The way your question is phrased implies your looking for the latter, so I'll try to focus on that. The page in the docs is the one right after the one you linked: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/pubsub .

You're going to need to make a call to the exposed websocket (or rpc, if you prefer - I'm sticking with websockets since you mentioned them in the question). You could use Postman for this if you like. (If someone has a cleaner way of doing this, please suggest it.) In order to subscribe to receive new blocks as they're added to the chain, and then to include all txs in the block, send:

```
{"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newHeads", {"includeTransactions": true}]}
```

If you're using the default websocket settings, for instance, that object should be sent to `localhost:8546`.

You should receive an object of data in return, something like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xcd0c3e8af590364c09d0fa6a1210faf5"}
```

The `result` is your subscription id. You should now get a stream of data over websockets. Take note of your subscription id, you'll need it if you want to unsubscribe.

Comment: Thank you. It seems the `localhost:8546` would be my need. I have to check it out...

Comment: If this answered your question, it would be a big help if you accepted the answer. (That's the checkmark under the arrows for voting on the question.) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web3js, look at [web3.eth.subscribe](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-subscribe.html) function.  It implements asynchronous notifications about various blockchain events, such as new blocks or event logs.  Under the hood it just polls the node periodically, as `geth` doesn't support push notifications.
For token transfers you need to subscribe to `transfer` event.  For ether transfer things are a bit more complicated, as there is no simple way to iterate through all the ether transfers within a block.
Here is nice undocumented feature, that could help monitoring balances of large sets of addresses effectively: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/15512

Let me know, if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail. May you tell me your idea about the points 3 and 4 of consideration section of https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/pubsub? Imagine I subscribed for many account addresses. How can I find I have lost the connection? And what should I do after it? Should I subscribe for all accounts again in such case?

Comment: Oh, good.  This means that `web3.eth.subscribe` doesn't use polling internally.  For handling disconnects, probably this will help: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1354#issuecomment-419510627